# Class vs. static method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I know this will work:

```
function Foo() {};
Foo.prototype.talk = function () {
    alert('hello~\n');
};

var a = new Foo;
a.talk(); // 'hello~\n'
```

But if I want to call

```
Foo.talk() // this will not work
Foo.prototype.talk() // this works correctly
```

I find some methods to make `Foo.talk` work,

1. `Foo.__proto__ = Foo.prototype`
2. `Foo.talk = Foo.prototype.talk`

Are there other ways to do this? I don’t know whether it is right to do so. Do you use class methods or static methods in your JavaScript code?

Comment: `Foo.talk = function ...`

Comment: @downvoterstepintothelight The `Foo.walk = function() {}` won't effect its instances, as it is not on the prototype chain. Is there cross-browser a method to make a function's `[[prototype]]` point to its `prototype`?

Comment: probably i have no idea what you want, because **class methods do not affect instances** by definition.

Comment: @downvoterstepintothelight I doubt that, [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)), in language like python, an instance is able to call its class method, the difference is `this` pointer.

Answer (score 431, accepted):

First off, remember that JavaScript is primarily a [prototypal language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), rather than a [class-based language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming)<sup>1</sup>. `Foo` isn't a class, it's a function, which is an object. You can instantiate an object *from* that function using the `new` keyword which will allow you to create something similar to a class in a standard OOP language.

I'd suggest ignoring `__proto__` most of the time because it has poor cross browser support, and instead focus on learning about how `prototype` works.

If you have an instance of an object created from a function<sup>2</sup> and you access one of its members (methods, attributes, properties, constants etc) in any way, the access will flow down the prototype hierarchy until it either (a) finds the member, or (b) doesn't find another prototype.

The hierarchy starts on the object that was called, and then searches its prototype object. If the prototype object has a prototype, it repeats, if no prototype exists, `undefined` is returned.

For example:

```
foo = {bar: 'baz'};
console.log(foo.bar); // logs "baz"

foo = {};
console.log(foo.bar); // logs undefined

function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype = {bar: 'baz'};
f = new Foo();
console.log(f.bar);
// logs "baz" because the object f doesn't have an attribute "bar"
// so it checks the prototype
f.bar = 'buzz';
console.log( f.bar ); // logs "buzz" because f has an attribute "bar" set
```

---

It looks to me like you've at least somewhat understood these "basic" parts already, but I need to make them explicit just to be sure.

In JavaScript, everything is an object<sup>3</sup>.

**everything** is an object.

`function Foo(){}` doesn't just define a new function, it defines a new function object that can be accessed using `Foo`.

This is why you can access `Foo`'s prototype with `Foo.prototype`.

What you can also do is set *more functions* on `Foo`:

```
Foo.talk = function () {
  alert('hello world!');
};
```

This new function can be accessed using:

```
Foo.talk();
```

I hope by now you're noticing a similarity between functions on a function object and a static method.

Think of `f = new Foo();` as creating a class instance, `Foo.prototype.bar = function(){...}` as defining a shared method for the class, and `Foo.baz = function(){...}` as defining a public static method for the class.

---

ECMAScript 2015 introduced a variety of syntactic sugar for these sorts of declarations to make them simpler to implement while also being easier to read. The previous example can therefore be written as:

```
class Foo {
  bar() {...}

  static baz() {...}
}
```

which allows `bar` to be called as:

```
const f = new Foo()
f.bar()
```

and `baz` to be called as:

```
Foo.baz()
```

---

<sub>1: [`class` was a "Future Reserved Word" in the ECMAScript 5 specification](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1.2), but ES6 introduces the ability to define classes using the `class` keyword.</sub>

<sub>2: essentially a class instance created by a constructor, but there are many nuanced differences that I don't want to mislead you</sub>

<sub>3: [primitive values](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.2)—which include `undefined`, `null`, booleans, numbers, and strings—aren't technically objects because they're low-level language implementations. Booleans, numbers, and strings still interact with the prototype chain as though they were objects, so for the purposes of this answer, it's easier to consider them "objects" even though they're not quite.</sub>

Comment: Well, just want to make it somehow like oop languages. Should I use `Foo.talk = Foo.prototype.talk` to avoid duplicate definition of `talk`?

Comment: @lostyzd - why is it a method to begin with? Either it uses `this` and needs to be called as an instance method, or it doesn't use `this` and you can make it a simple attribute of `Foo` (and have instances call `Foo.talk()`).

Comment: @nrabinowitz I try to make instances have the access to its constructor's method(static method).

Comment: @lostyzd - well, they can access it, through `Foo.talk()`. You could assign that in the constructor, if you want: `this.talk = Foo.talk` - or, as you note, by assigning `Foo.prototype.talk = Foo.talk`. But I'm not sure this is a good idea - on principle, instance methods should be specific to the instance.

Comment: I might be confused about your intent, but in your example, "a" is your instance. And "a" has access to the constructor's method, because you can call "a.talk()". In JS, you would very rarely have a reason to call Foo.talk() — this is essentially calling a method on the constructor, when the OO pattern would be to simple create an instance FROM the constructor and call it on that instance (a.talk).

Comment: @Doug Avery, `Foo.talk()` is just calling a namespaced function. You'd use it in situations similar to how static methods are called in OOP languages like Java/C#. A good example of a use case would be a function like [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

Comment: Well put, thank you. I am coming to Javascript from an OOP background (Python / C++), and I find it mind boggling how many ways there are to do things in this language. I need static methods for a geometry module, which I intend to use like so: `var distance_squared = Geometry.Sphere.distance_squared.AABox(a_spherical_object, an_axis_aligned_rectangular_object);`

Comment: Isn't what he was originally asking just like Array().splice.call()?

Comment: P.S. null is object
typeof null == 'object'

Comment: @mvladk, Yea, I've been meaning to update this post, as value objects aren't fully fledged objects either.

Comment: The fundamental point you are all missing is that static methods get inherited. `Foo.talk = function ()...` wont be available to subclasses on there own class name. This can be worked around by "extending" subclasses, but I'm also still looking for a more elegant way.

Comment: @nus, only some languages allow static methods to be inherited. If inheritance is desired you shouldn't be using static methods to begin with.

Comment: Can static method access property defined in class?

Comment: @AlanKis If you're interested in accessing a non-static property, then you'd typically access it using a non-static function.

Comment: I want to remark that JavaScript is indeed OOP! It has all the fundamental features: dynamic dispatch, encapsulation, subtyping, open recursion. The absent of class-concept is compensated by the prototype-concept. Classes were just a additional feature.

Answer (score 69):

You can achieve it as below:

```
function Foo() {};

Foo.talk = function() { alert('I am talking.'); };
```

You can now invoke "talk" function as below:

```
Foo.talk();
```

You can do this because in JavaScript, functions are objects as well.

Answer (score 40):

Call a static method from an instance:

```
function Clazz() {};
Clazz.staticMethod = function() {
    alert('STATIC!!!');
};

Clazz.prototype.func = function() {
    this.constructor.staticMethod();
}

var obj = new Clazz();
obj.func(); // <- Alert's "STATIC!!!"
```

Simple Javascript Class Project: https://github.com/reduardo7/sjsClass

Comment: This is not a static call.  var obj = new Clazz(); creates a new _instance_ of Clazz.  However, Clazz.staticMethod() achieves the result without all of that other stuff.

Comment: @mpemburn: Eduardo is also correct in his answer. What he's showing you is not only can you call the static method from "outside" via `Clazz.staticMethod` but he's showing you how to link to these static methods from within an instantiated object.   This is especially useful in enviornments like Node.js where, using require, you may not have direct access to the original constructor.  The only thing I would add is `this.constructor.staticMethod.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: Absolutely awesome, even works inside a coffee-script constructor: `constructor: (a) -> @constructor.add @` (well almost, anyway)

Answer (score 35):

Here is a good example to demonstrate how Javascript works with static/instance variables and methods.

```
function Animal(name) {
    Animal.count = Animal.count+1||1;// static variables, use function name "Animal"
    this.name = name; //instance variable, using "this"
}

Animal.showCount = function () {//static method
    alert(Animal.count)
}

Animal.prototype.showName=function(){//instance method
    alert(this.name);
}

var mouse = new Animal("Mickey");
var elephant = new Animal("Haddoop");

Animal.showCount();  // static method, count=2
mouse.showName();//instance method, alert "Mickey"
mouse.showCount();//Error!! mouse.showCount is not a function, which is different from  Java
```

Comment: Good point : This could be weird not to have access to static function through `this`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution this is what i was looking in which situation there will be access of `this` keyword

Answer (score 33):

In additions, now it is possible to do with `class` and `static`

```
'use strict'

class Foo {
 static talk() {
     console.log('talk')
 };

 speak() {
     console.log('speak')
 };

};
```

will give

```
var a = new Foo();
Foo.talk();  // 'talk'
a.talk();    // err 'is not a function'
a.speak();   // 'speak'
Foo.speak(); // err 'is not a function'
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as examples are worth a thousand words. However, it doesn't explain why `a.talk()` doesn't work. The accepted answer says the chain of prototypes should find it, right? But it's not the case

Comment: You can add  `talk() { Foo.talk();}` if you really need `a.talk()`

Answer (score 12):

I use namespaces:

```
var Foo = {
     element: document.getElementById("id-here"),

     Talk: function(message) {
            alert("talking..." + message);
     },

     ChangeElement: function() {
            this.element.style.color = "red";
     }
};
```

And to use it:

```
Foo.Talk("Testing");
```

Or

```
Foo.ChangeElement();
```

Answer (score 7):

ES6 supports now `class` & `static` keywords like a charm :

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {}

    talk() {
        console.log("i am not static");
    }

    static saying() {
        console.log(this.speech);
    }

    static get speech() {
        return "i am static method";
    }

}
```

Comment: I was looking for answer like this. Can static method call non-static methods/variables?

Comment: @Tomasz static methods won't have ´this´ set to any instance of the class, but rather the class itself. So of course, a static method *can* call an instance method, but only if it somehow has access to an instance, such as ´static staticMethod() { new Foo().talk(); }´

Answer (score 4):

If you have to write static methods in ES5 I found a great tutorial for that:

```
//Constructor
var Person = function (name, age){
//private properties
var priv = {};

//Public properties
this.name = name;
this.age = age;

//Public methods
this.sayHi = function(){
    alert('hello');
}
}


// A static method; this method only 
// exists on the class and doesn't exist  
// on child objects
Person.sayName = function() {
   alert("I am a Person object ;)");  
};
```

see @https://abdulapopoola.com/2013/03/30/static-and-instance-methods-in-javascript/

Answer (score 4):

Just additional notes. Using class ES6, When we create static methods..the Javacsript engine set the descriptor attribute a lil bit different from the old-school "static" method

```
function Car() {

}

Car.brand = function() {
  console.log('Honda');
}

console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Car)
);
```

it sets internal attribute (descriptor property) for brand() to

```
..
brand: [object Object] {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    value: ..
    writable: true

}
..
```

compared to

```
class Car2 {
   static brand() {
     console.log('Honda');
   }
}

console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Car2)
);
```

that sets internal attribute for brand() to

```
..
brand: [object Object] {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value:..
    writable: true
  }

..
```

see that **enumerable** is set to **false** for static method in ES6.

it means you cant use the for-in loop to check the object

```
for (let prop in Car) {
  console.log(prop); // brand
}

for (let prop in Car2) {
  console.log(prop); // nothing here
}
```

static method in ES6 is treated like other's class private property (name, length, constructor) except that static method is still writable thus the descriptor **writable** is set to **true** `{ writable: true }`. it also means that we can override it

```
Car2.brand = function() {
   console.log('Toyota');
};

console.log(
  Car2.brand() // is now changed to toyota
);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you try to call `Foo.talk`, the JS tries to search a function `talk` through `__proto__` and, of course, it can't be found.

`Foo.__proto__` is `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

Static method calls are made directly on the class and are not callable on instances of the class. Static methods are often used to 
create utility function

Pretty clear description

[Taken Directly from mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

Foo needs to be bound to your class
Then when you create a new instance you can call myNewInstance.foo()
If you import your class you can call a static method

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you want to `Foo.talk()`:

```
function Foo() {};
// But use Foo.talk would be inefficient
Foo.talk = function () {
    alert('hello~\n');
};

Foo.talk(); // 'hello~\n'
```

But it's an inefficient way to implement, using `prototype` is better.

---

Another way, My way is defined as static class:

```
var Foo = new function() {
  this.talk = function () {
    alert('hello~\n');
    };
};

Foo.talk(); // 'hello~\n'
```

Above static class doesn't need to use `prototype` because it will be only constructed once as static usage.

> https://github.com/yidas/js-design-patterns/tree/master/class

Answer (score 0):

When i faced such a situation, i have done something like this:

```
Logger = {
    info: function (message, tag) {
        var fullMessage = '';        
        fullMessage = this._getFormatedMessage(message, tag);
        if (loggerEnabled) {
            console.log(fullMessage);
        }
    },
    warning: function (message, tag) {
        var fullMessage = '';
        fullMessage = this._getFormatedMessage(message, tag);
        if (loggerEnabled) {
            console.warn(fullMessage);`enter code here`
        }
    },
    _getFormatedMessage: function () {}
};
```

so now i can call the info method as 
`Logger.info("my Msg", "Tag");`

Comment: I do this all the time, but it's basically just namespacing. It doesn't allow you to create instances with instance vars?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no actual classes rather it uses a system of prototypal inheritance in which objects 'inherit' from other objects via their prototype chain. This is best explained via code itself:

```js
function Foo() {};
// creates a new function object

Foo.prototype.talk = function () {
    console.log('hello~\n');
};
// put a new function (object) on the prototype (object) of the Foo function object

var a = new Foo;
// When foo is created using the new keyword it automatically has a reference 
// to the prototype property of the Foo function

// We can show this with the following code
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(a) === Foo.prototype); 

a.talk(); // 'hello~\n'
// When the talk method is invoked it will first look on the object a for the talk method,
// when this is not present it will look on the prototype of a (i.e. Foo.prototype)

// When you want to call
// Foo.talk();
// this will not work because you haven't put the talk() property on the Foo
// function object. Rather it is located on the prototype property of Foo.

// We could make it work like this:
Foo.sayhi = function () {
    console.log('hello there');
};

Foo.sayhi();
// This works now. However it will not be present on the prototype chain 
// of objects we create out of Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

There are tree ways methods and properties are implemented on function or class objects, and on they instances.

1. **On the class** (or function) itself : `Foo.method()` or `Foo.prop`. Those are static methods or properties
2. **On its prototype** : `Foo.prototype.method()` or `Foo.prototype.prop`. When created, the instances will inherit those object via the prototype witch is `{method:function(){...}, prop:...}`. So the *foo* object will receive, as prototype, a copy of the *Foo.prototype* object.
3. **On the instance itself** : the method or property is added to the object itself. `foo={method:function(){...}, prop:...}`

The `this` keyword will represent and act differently according to the context. In a static method, it will represent the class itself (witch is after all an instance of Function  : `class Foo {}` is quite equivalent to `let Foo = new Function({})`

With ECMAScript 2015, that seems well implemented today, it is clearer to see the difference between class (*static*) methods and properties, instance methods and properties and own methods ans properties. You can thus create **three method or properties having the same name, but being different** because they apply to different objects, the `this` keyword, in methods, will apply to, respectively, the class object itself and the instance object, by the prototype or by its own.

```
class Foo {
  constructor(){super();}
  
  static prop = "I am static" // see 1.
  static method(str) {alert("static method"+str+" :"+this.prop)} // see 1.
  
  prop="I am of an instance"; // see 2.
  method(str) {alert("instance method"+str+" : "+this.prop)} // see 2.
}

var foo= new Foo();
foo.prop = "I am of own";  // see 3.
foo.func = function(str){alert("own method" + str + this.prop)} // see 3.
```