# Basic Object/Prototype Syntax Issues

Tags: javascript

Can someone clear up what I'm doing wrong with my code? I'm a total newb, simply trying to experiment with how to create objects, prototypes, and what the this command refers to in the context of prototypes. However, none of my code is working on jFiddle. I know this code is completely nonsensical, but I'm just trying to find out what the document prints in various cases to get a more concrete grasp of how objects, prototypes, constructors, and the "this" keyword works. But NOTHING is showing up at all!

```
function Person(identity) {
    this.identity = "fellow";
    this.logYou = function() {
        document.write('hi');
    };
};
Person.prototype.logMe = function() {
    document.write(this.identity);
};

var Dude = new Person("stud");

Person.logYou();  
Person.logMe();
Dude.logMe();
```

​

Comment: You can read about prototype and prototypal inheritance in [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201082/prototypal-inheritance-concept-in-javascript-as-a-prototype-based-language)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201082/prototypal-inheritance-concept-in-javascript-as-a-prototype-based-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Person() {
  this.identity = "fellow";
  this.logYou = function() {
    document.write('hi');
  };
};
```

When you call `this.identity = "fellow";` the `this` keyword refers the **context** in which the function is running.
So if you call the function in the Global scope, `this` refers to `window` object:

```
Person();
alert(window.identity); // fellow
```

And if you instanciate the function, `this` keyword refers to the new object:

```
var Dude = new Person();
alert(Dude.identity); // fellow
```

So the function `Person` has no property `identity`.
If you want to have some property for your function:

```
Person.identity = "fellow";
alert(Person.identity); //  fellow
```

Answer (score 1):

`logYou` and `logMe` are methods stored on the prototype of `Person` so that inheriting objects may have that function to call. You can't call `logYou` on `Person` but what you *can* do is call it on its child, `Dude`:

```
Dude.logYou(); // hi
Dude.logMe(); // fellow
```

Answer (score 1):

These two lines

```
Person.logYou();   
Person.logMe();
```

throw an error an couse the code to stop executing because `logYou` and `logMe` do not exist as properties of `Person`.

`Dude.logMe()` and `Dude.logYou()` will work, printing `fellow` and `hi`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call

```
Person.logYou();  
Person.logMe();
```

as Person has no method `logYou` or `logMe`, when you remove these two lines, your code will start working