# Method on constructor’s prototype throws TypeError when called

Tags: javascript

I have created a function constructor which returns a new array with given parameters. I am trying to add a custom method `sumUp` using the `prototype` property. The function constructor returns the array as expected. But when I call that method it is throwing the error:

> TypeError: `newArr.sumUp` is not a function

```js
function SurajArray(...array) {
  let arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    arr.push(array[i]);
  }

  return arr;
}

SurajArray.prototype.sumUp = function() {
  let ans = this.reduce((result, value) => {
    result = result + value;
    
    return result;
  }, 0);

  return ans;
}

let newArr = new SurajArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

console.log(newArr); // gives correct array
console.log(typeof sumUp); // gives undefined

let sum = newArr.sumUp(); // This gives an error

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Not sure why you expect `typeof sumUp` to yield anything other than `"undefined"`. `sumUp` is a property of an object, not a global variable.

Comment: `newArr instanceof SurajArray` is `false`. You’re just returning an Array; you’re not actually extending the prototype chain. See [Good Example of JavaScript's Prototype-Based Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064731/4642212) and [prototypal inheritance concept in javascript as a prototype based language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12201082/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon - Just beware that you can't extend `Array` with the patterns used in most of those answers (one of them has a `class` example, which does work). `Array` and `Error` couldn't be properly subclassed in ES5 and earlier. They can now in ES2015+, easily with `class` syntax and slightly less easily with `function` and `Reflect.construct`. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constructor does not need a return value. The prototype of a constructor function can be used to manipulate instance values (`this...`). So, the most simple and prototypal translation of your function(s) will be:

```js
// the constructor
function SurajArray(...array) {
  // assign array to the instance (this)
  this.arr = array;
  // if sumUp does not exist in the prototype, create it
  SurajArray.prototype.sumUp = SurajArray.prototype.sumUp || function() { 
    return this.arr.reduce( (acc, val) => acc + val, 0); 
    //     ^ the instance value
  };
  // Note: this is mostly done outside the constructor function,
  // but this also works
}
// create 2 instances
const sa1 = new SurajArray(21, 23, 45);
const sa2 = new SurajArray(300, 17, 98);
console.log(sa1.sumUp());
console.log(sa2.sumUp());
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `SurajArray` function just returns a plain array, which won't use `SurajArray.prototype` as its prototype, so won't have a `sumUp` function on it, so the result of calling it (whether via `new` or otherwise) won't have a `sumUp` function. (There's also no global `sumUp` function, so the code looking for one won't find it.)

To correctly subclass an array, use `class` syntax and `extends`:¹

```js
class SurajArray extends Array {
    sumUp() {
        let ans = this.reduce((result, value) => {
            result = result + value;
            return result;
        }, 0);
        return ans;
    }
}

const newArr = new SurajArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
const sum = newArr.sumUp();
console.log(sum);
```

Or more simply:

```js
class SurajArray extends Array {
    sumUp() {
        let sum = 0;
        for (const value of this) {
            sum += value;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

const newArr = new SurajArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
const sum = newArr.sumUp();
console.log(sum);
```

---

¹ It's also possible, in ES2015 and later, to subclass `Array` with `function` syntax and [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct), but it's simpler with `class` and if you're going to use `new` anyway, it makes sense to go with simple. (Prior to ES2015, you couldn't properly subclass `Array`.) Just for completeness, this is what it looks like:

```js
// The constructor
function SurajArray(...args) {
    return Reflect.construct(Array, args, SurajArray);
}
// A correctly-set up `SurajArray.prototype` object
SurajArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
SurajArray.prototype.constructor = SurajArray;
// A method -- by default, instance methods should be non-enumerable
// as this one is (because the default for the `enumerable` flag is
// false)
Object.defineProperty(SurajArray.prototype, "sumUp", {
    value() {
        let sum = 0;
        for (const value of this) {
            sum += value;
        }
        return sum;
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
});

// Usage example
const newArr = new SurajArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
const sum = newArr.sumUp();
console.log(sum);
```

(Note that additional methods it defines can't correctly use `super`, though.)