# code refactoring. Method that operates on all instances of the class

Tags: javascript, oop, refactoring

I have a class constructor whose main work is to instantiate Objects. It takes ID, checks that object with such ID was not created before and creates it.

```
function Vehicle(ID){
    if (this.listOfVehicles.indexOf(ID) !== -1) throw new Error('Vehicle with such ID already exists');
    this.ID = ID;
    this.listOfVehicles.push(ID);
    this.isMoving = true;
}
```

Prototype of the object has the storage of all the object IDs and two methods run - which makes the vehicle moving and stopAll, which stops all vehicles.

```
Vehicle.prototype = {
    'listOfVehicles' : [],
    'run'            : function(){
        this.isMoving = true;
    },
    'stopAll'           : function(){
        var vehicleID, i, listOfVehicles = Vehicle.prototype.listOfVehicles;
        for(i = 0; i < listOfVehicles.length; i++){
            vehicleID = listOfVehicles[i];
            vehicles[vehicleID].isMoving = false;
        }
    }
};
```

Basically everything is working nicely:

```
var vehicles = {};
vehicles[3] = new Vehicle(3);
vehicles[6] = new Vehicle(6);
vehicles[12] = new Vehicle(12);
```

All vehicles are instantiated and moving

```
vehicles[3].stopAll();
```

All vehicles are not moving

```
vehicles[3].run();
```

only vehicle 3 i moving

There is one thing, I do not like here. In order to stop all vehicles I need to use method from some of the vehicles. But I can not think of any better way of doing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [class/static method in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694501/class-static-method-in-javascript)

Comment: I just tried it, that's not true. I defined `Vehicle.static()`, then instantiated `v = new Vehicle(3);`. When I tried `v.static();` I got an error saying it has no such method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define:

```
Vehicle.stopAll = function () {
    var vehicleID, i, listOfVehicles = Vehicle.prototype.listOfVehicles;
    for(i = 0; i < listOfVehicles.length; i++){
        vehicleID = listOfVehicles[i];
        vehicles[vehicleID].isMoving = false;
    }
}
```

There's actually nothing requiring you to attach this function to the class, you could also define it as:

```
function stopAllVehicles () {
    var vehicleID, i, listOfVehicles = Vehicle.prototype.listOfVehicles;
    for(i = 0; i < listOfVehicles.length; i++){
        vehicleID = listOfVehicles[i];
        vehicles[vehicleID].isMoving = false;
    }
}
```

because Javascript classes don't implement information hiding (you can do that yourself by enclosing information in local variables of functions).

Or you can use your original class definition, and use `Vehicle.prototype.stopAll()`. Since JS uses prototype-based OO, there's always a vehicle available to call the method on.