# Confused about whether Javascript object should contain function to iterate over itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller

I'm creating a chat application in Node.js using MVC design. I'm confused about whether certain methods should belong to the 'Room' object or the 'User' object. I need these methods:

```
checkIfUserExists(users_array)
checkIfRoomExists(rooms_array)
```

If this was C++, I may have created static functions to do this in their respective classes, but I'm not sure what the best practice in Javascript is. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have a Room on which to call a method, then clearly it exists. It would seem that you'd want the `checkIfRoomExists` to be on whatever it is that holds a set of Room objects. But then you've provided very little as far as a concrete example of the problem, so who knows...

Comment: You might want to give an example as to how your arrays should look like. I'll take a shot in the dark here, and say that these functions should not exist to begin with (unless during debugging, when you simply want to make sure that your code does not, for ex. accidentally put non-user objects into an array of user objects).

Comment: My Room object holds a Users array that contains all the users in the room. checkifUserExists() function is to check server-side whether a user exists already(duplicate) before adding him to the array. 
Similarly I'll need to check whether a Room exists before allowing the User to create the room.

Comment: I basically have two models: User(just contains data like name and id) and Group(contains array of all current users).

Comment: what about Room.hasUser(userID) and User.isInRoom(roomID) hm ?

Comment: This isn't a JavaScript problem.. It is an OOP problem

Comment: Although JS is a prototypal language, [you can define a static method on a JS class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7694501/1202461).

Comment: I mean, if you need static methods - use them, especially if this will make your code easier to write / read / maintain / debug.