# Redefining Methods to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

So I have a Javascript function i.e

```
var object = function(){
    function sayHello(){
       console.log("Hello");
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to redefine the object.sayHello method later on in my code such that instead it prints "Bonjour"?

Comment: Did you mean `function Object() { ... }; var object = new Object();`?

Comment: No, object is defined as a function. Later on I do initialize a  var newObj = new object. I think the two function the same though.

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/r490an2h/ edit: your code doesn't create `object.sayHello`

Comment: I appreciate the help, but what you made was an object, object needs to be a function in my case.

Comment: You are right, I really only need to be able to call sayHello() inside of object, but I want to modify it elsewhere, does that makes sense?

Comment: In that case you need to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/r490an2h/1/ (a function doesn't have methods, afaik)

Comment: So I need to do just that but before I create a new object for "object". I want to modify the function as a whole, and not just an instance of the function.

Comment: Read this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7694583/1161948

Comment: Thank you for the help, I finally figured it out. I just needed to make 
    var object = function(){
      function sayHello(){
             sayHi();
     }
    }
and then define sayHi() outside of 'object' so whenever I wanted to change the functionality of sayHello(), I just override sayHi(). Also this implementation allows you to use the privileged methods of sayHello() if you also pass 'self' to sayHi().

Answer (score 0):

You can override functions in Javascript.  All you have to do is re-declare it later on.

```js
var hello = function(){
    alert("Hello");
}

function changeFunction(){
    hello = function(){
     alert("Goodbye");
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Run Function</button>
<button onclick="changeFunction()">Change function</button>
```

Comment: Which function? Hello() is a global variable, you can change it from any location, inside any other function you want.

Comment: So Hello() has another function inside of it, sayHello(), look at the original code sample I posted, and I want to only change the sayHello() function inside of Hello() without redeclaring the entire function. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, there is no way to reference only the nested function.

Answer (score 0):

js

```
var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
var object = function(){
    function sayHello(input){
       console.log(input);
    } 
}
```

and html

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="input" placeholder="enter greetings">
```