# JS equivalent to PHP's new static()

Tags: javascript, php, static

I have a abstract base class that controls a lot of the heavy lifting for subclasses, and I want to add a static factory method to insatiate the object that would work in a similar way to PHP's `static` keyword.

I am currently calling the abstract classes static method and passing it a constructor of a subclass type: `Subclass.fromFile({}, Subclass)`, which is so elegant.

**Current Implementation**

```
class AbstractClass {
    //...

    static fromFile(attributes, constructor) {
        return new constructor(attributes)
    }

    //...
}
```

**Is there a JS equivalent to PHP's `new static()`?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class vs. static method in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694501/class-vs-static-method-in-javascript)

Comment: This question has to do with instantiation of a new object not calling methods on an existing one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is almost trivial. Apparently JS passes `this` to static methods as the caller's `class` instance.

You can therefore instantiate the object using `new this(args)` from within the static method.

**Example**

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    static fromFile(attributes) {
        console.log(this) // [LOG] class A {}
        return new this(attributes)
    }
}

class A extends AbstractClass {}

console.log(A.fromFile([])) // [LOG] A
```