# StandardJS and React class export Unexpected token =

Tags: reactjs, standardjs

Can anyone shed some light on the notice I am getting back from StandardJS?

> Parsing error: Unexpected token =

Code is as follows:

```
export default class foreignDataFormat extends _base {
    static input = class ForeignDataFormatInput extends React.Component {
        render () {

        }
    }
}
```

The error is referring to the second line `input = class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, class cannot be defined as static. But method can be defined as static. You would just define (and probably mean to define) the class like:

```
export default class foreignDataFormat extends _base {
    const input = class ForeignDataFormatInput extends React.Component {
        static myMethod() { 
          //... my static method
        }
        render () {

        }
    }
}
```

You may be interested to see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033102/2138752).

Comment: Many thanks @BhojendraRauniyar I was trying to use the `static class feature` thats currently in proposal state.

Updated to the following and my warnings are now gone.

`export default class foreignDataFormat extends _base {}

foreignDataFormat.input = class ForeignDataFormatInput extends React.Component {
    render () {
    }
}`