# JavaScript Class Static Method, but in function?

Tags: javascript

As far as I know there are 2 ways to create classes in javascript, with functions or class statements.
If in the statement class, you can create static methods using static keywords.
Then if it functions, how do you create static methods?

```
class SomeClass {
  myMethod() {
    console.log("Some");
  }
}

// equivalent to

function SomeClass() {
  this.myMethod = function() {
    console.log("Some");
  }
}

==================================================
==================================================
//Now static method

class SomeClass {
  static myMethod() {
    console.log("Some");
  }
}

// equivalent to

function SomeClass() {
  ???
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class vs. static method in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694501/class-vs-static-method-in-javascript) — `Object.assign(SomeClass, { myStaticMethod1(...args){` … `}, myStaticMethod2(...args){` … `} })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static methods are simply methods put on the function itself. So, it's rather:

```
class SomeClass {
  static myMethod() {
    console.log("Some");
  }
}

// equivalent to

function SomeClass() {}

SomeClass.myMethod = function(){
  console.log("Some")
}
```

---

Also note (although this is off topic to your question), that your first two codes aren't *equal*.

They *behave identically* up to a point, but they're different.

`class`es define methods on their prototype, while your `function` stuff creates it on a per-instance basis. Thus:

```
class SomeClass {
  myMethod() {
    console.log("Some");
  }
}

function SomeFn() {
  this.myMethod = function() {
    console.log("Some");
  }
}

const a = new SomeClass
const b = new SomeFn
const a2 = new SomeClass
const b2 = new SomeFn

a.myMethod() //Some
b.myMethod() //Some

console.log(a.myMethod === a2.myMethod) //true
console.log(b.myMethod === b2.myMethod) //false
```

Therefore, it rather should be:

```
class SomeClass {
  myMethod() {
    console.log("Some");
  }
}

// equivalent to

function SomeClass() {}

SomeClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    console.log("Some");
}
```

Comment: … which is already covered by the answers in the proposed duplicate target.

Comment: @user4642212 That's true, but I started writing before you found it. I did a quick search, but found nothing...