# TypeError, is not a function error in NodejS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a class that contains few functions, putting one of then below,

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const ObjectId = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId;
const mockLookUps = require(“../../data”).mockLookUps;

class XYZ {
   // ...... Other functions
   async getData() {
    return Promise.resolve(mockLookUps); // JSON Object
  }
}

module.exports = XYZ;
```

if I import that in other class like below,

```
const x = await XYZ.getData();
```

It is throwing me some is not a function error like this,

```
XYZ.getData is not a function
```

What is the mistake I'm making?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class vs. static method in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694501/class-vs-static-method-in-javascript)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: By the way, no need for `Promise.resolve` since your method is `async` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const xyz = new XYZ()
const data = await xyz.getData()
```

Could work

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You have to create a class instance first to call instance methods.

try this:

```
const xyz = new XYZ();
const result = await xyz.getData();
```

**2.** For your case try to make it static:

```
class XYZ {
   // ...... Other functions
   static async getData() {
    return Promise.resolve(mockLookUps); // JSON Object
  }
}

module.exports = XYZ;
```

and then you can use so:

```
const x = await XYZ.getData();
```